# Mat Cell Def pass index Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, split, angular-material, angular8

I have created a table using Angular Materials. For one particular column, I am passing an array of values.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="data">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Data </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" class="tag"> {{element.data}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

I am trying to apply CSS styling to each element of data. I am receiving data from DB and it is passing me the data value as a string like:

```
"data": "abc,def,gef"
```

I am splitting this data into 3 strings on `,` and creating an array. I now want to use this array to bind and apply css to 3 separate strings but I am getting one single long string on which the css is applied

This is my TS code

```
 for (let i = 0; i <= this.userData.data.length; i++){
           this.splitted[i] = this.userData.data[i].abc.split(',');
           this.splittedString.push(this.splitted[i]);
           this.userData.data[i]['abc'] = this.splittedString[i];
```

Comment: do you have any live demo to share ?

Comment: no I do not have anything live as these values are all dynamic.

Comment: no actually this entire data is completely dynamic

Comment: I was talking about recreating your problem in something like stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-getting-started-xpndxn?file=src/app/product-list/product-list.component.ts

Comment: this is the closest to what I am trying to implement

Comment: but I am using angular material